# Php Emails Character Codification

Tags: php, email

i'm using the following code to send e-mails from php.

```
    $to = 'myemail@domain.com'; 
$subject = 'Test email with attachment'; 
$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
$headers = "From: webmaster@example.com\r\nReply-To: webmaster@example.com"; 
$headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\""; 
if(isset($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name']) && $_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name'] != ''){ $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['tmp_name']))); }
ob_start();
?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>" 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello World!!! 
This is simple text email message. 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<h2>Hello World!</h2> 
<p>This is something with <b>HTML</b> formatting.</p> 

--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>-- 

<?php if(isset($_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name']) && $_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name'] != ''){ ?>--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: application/zip; name="<?php echo $_FILES['curriculum_vitae']['name']; ?>"  
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64  
Content-Disposition: attachment  

<?php echo $attachment; ?> 
--PHP-mixed-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
<?php } ?>
<?php 
$message = ob_get_clean(); 
$mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers ); 
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

However, when i receive the email on the webmail i have problems with the character codification. Characters like "à" or "ç" appears in strange forms.

Is this a problem of the codification i have defined in the code above?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you sending the diffrent2 type of content-type and heading?

Comment: well, i find this piece of code om internet and adapted some parts, i didn't change that part, should i?

Comment: the worst code you are using no need to do all of this jus t make it simple.see my answer.

Comment: already solved, thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change headers to UTF8

in the `text/plain` part

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

and in the `text/html` part

```
--PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>  
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8" 
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this use this code to send mail using php script

```
<?php
$to = "someone@example.com";
$subject = "Test mail";
$message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
$from = "someonelse@example.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

No need to set an additional information on script.i dont know why you are settling sevral headers  and content-type encoding.